# How do I make my Favorites icons fit their squares?

Tags: safari, catalina, icon, library

Here's a pic of what I'm talking about.

[image]

I already know how to change the icons (by going to ~/Library/Safari/Touch Icons Cache/Images/ then replacing them with the same named .png) but some of them don't fit perfectly like the Facebook, Twitter, or "Day 1 Advent of Code" icon does. Btw, I'm not so bothered about the Reddit icon not fitting since it's not a square so please ignore that.
Is there any way to solve this?

I already tried resizing but it stayed the same. Let me be clear that I'm doing this because I don't want any plain letters in my Favorites (such as the "U" you'll see in the pic). I also checked the sizes of those icons who fit perfectly, and some were even smaller than the ones that do not occupy the entire square!

The sizes were all at least 144x144 px. From there I tried scaling up and it didn't work. The files were .png format. I also did not change the file names.

I hope someone can help me customize this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. So to rephrase, each web site donates an image and the ones that are small get a border. You want to somehow fake out the OS to none use the icons provided and put in higher quality or more pixel versions so you don’t get the border that the software does to avoid upsampling small art?

Comment: I changed them because if I don't, they'd just appear as plain letters in my Favorites

Comment: I’m not saying you’re wrong - I love the customization - just trying to make sure I understand what you want...

Comment: Pls see my edit, hope I explained clearly!

Comment: No - you didn’t say what size they are. You didn’t say which format you saved the pictures. It’s not much clearer at all to me. Here are the 2x icon sizes I recommend for macOS - https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/app-icon/ I’d go 1024/1024 here but maybe 512/512 would do assuming you want 512pt and no down sizing.

Comment: at least 144 px, and png

Answer (score 1):

If these are png files you can open them in Preview and adjust the size. Try to keep the proportions the same when you do this. In Preview there is a menu item Tools. Click on the and you'll see Change Size as an option. Click on that and it'll bring up the panel shown below.

[image]

On this panel, you can make your image any size you want. I think the icons are square so you can set them as 64x64 for example.

Comment: I already tried adjusting them :(

Comment: well you should have mentioned that in your question as things you have tried.  What happened when you set the size?

Comment: they still had borders

Comment: @jess - this is why I commented. If you are making these JPG or PNG and the exact details in terms of pixels all matter. Just edit your main question to put more details in the post - I’m sure we can help once it’s clear what you want and what you did so far...

Comment: post edited! pls check it

Comment: I would target 512 px absolute minimum here. If you are on retina - go 2x that @jess

Comment: It still didn't work unfortunately. but thanks for helping!

Comment: You could go into preview and copy the part of the icon you want and just use that part. This way you can cut out the border completely on all sides. Just blow the icon up and select the inside part to copy. Then blow up the image to the size you want...

Comment: @jmh I get what you mean, but no matter what size or what pixels I choose, Safari's still in control of the borders in the Favorites tab.

Comment: i'm out of ideas, sorry i couldn't help you!